# Change child window only border appears

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I create client area that can change whenever need to change. MainFrame is start point frame Application. Index, Dashboard is View for client area window by derive from CWnd. I'm not include event and implemetation button. cause thats not the problem. it will just make the code more longer. assume each button works. The problem is switch View. Index view disappears as expected. but the dashboard view only show border whereas OnCreate there's logout button. but not appears. I try to updatewindow and setwindowpos. button that inside dashboard still not appears.

gui.cpp

```
class MainFrame: public CFrameWnd
{
  afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT);
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
};   

int MainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if(CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
  {
    return -1;
  };

  CRect rect;
  GetClientRect(&rect);

  Index* index = new Index;
  index->CreateEx(
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    rect,
    this, NULL, NULL
  );

  return 0;
};
```

views/index.cpp

```
#define LOGIN_BTN 1

class Index: public CWnd
{
  void validate();

  afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT);
};

int Index::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if(CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
  {
    return -1;
  };

  CButton* loginBtn = new CButton;
  loginBtn->Create(
    "Login", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
    CRect(CPoint(0, 0), CSize(150, 25)), 
    this, LOGIN_BTN   
  );

  return 0;
};

void Index::validate()
{
  CRect rect;
  GetClientRect(&rect);

  Dashboard* dashboard = new Dashboard;
  dashboard->CreateEx(
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER,
    rect,
    AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd, NULL, NULL
  );

  DestroyWindow();
};
```

views/dashboard.cpp

```
#define LOGOUT_BTN 2

class Dashboard: public CWnd
{
  void logout();
  afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT);
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
};

int Dashboard::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if(CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
  {
    return -1;
  };

  CButton* logoutBtn = new CButton;
  logoutBtn->Create(
    "Logout", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
    CRect(CPoint(0, 0), CSize(150, 25)), 
    this, LOGOUT_BTN   
  );

  return 0;
};

void Dashboard::logout()
{
  Index* index = new Index;
  index->CreateEx(
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    rect,
    AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd, NULL, NULL
  );

  DestroyWindow();
};
```

Comment: Could you please zip your project and attach it here?
I see a couple of potential problems not related to your question, but to determine both the whole application source code would be very helpful.